# Facebook "Invalid redirect_uri", but the url looks fine to me

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm getting the following error when trying to authenticate to Facebook with OAuth:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

My url looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=283993944973616&redirect_uri=http://dennys-m.appspot.com/fb_login/&scope=publish_stream,email&display=popup
```

I know there are a lot of other posts with this problem, but I can't see what would make my url invalid. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your redirect url: http://dennys-m.appspot.com/fb_login/ must match the `canvas url` in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ configuration panel.

Fortunately, these days Facebook gives the error message `Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration`. About a year ago no such exception appeared, just strange results.

Answer (score 12):

In my case there was no `/` at the end of mine redirect uri! No comments to fb..

Answer (score 11):

You have to register your `redirect URL` at `Facebook console`

First go to  `Advanced` tab inside `Settings`

[image]

There after scroll down to `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`

register your `url` there the moment you will save changes it will stop giving this exception

[image]

Comment: that's what i was going to answer but u did it before

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `localhost:3000` as your call back url,
For example your call back uri may like: `http://localhost:3000/sessions/create`, where `sessions/create` are the controller and action respectively,
then make your Canvas URL as: `http://localhost:3000/`

Answer (score 1):

Something else:
It might sound stupid but read those snippets carefully.
[image: Facebook doc snippet]

It took me several **days** to figure out why I always got this error message

> Invalid redirect_uri URI is not supported

Those curley brackets are not a part of the URI!

Again, it might sound stupid and some of you out there might say "This would never happen to me" but if you are new into something use your brain ( I didn't ;) )

Comment: same thing bro)