# The redirect_uri URL is not supported

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I am using facebook app on two servers, dev and live. The dev server is hosted at **test.testdev.com** and live server is hosted at **test.testlive.net**. Earlier it was working properly on both the servers but now it works only on dev.

When I try to access it on live server it displays the following error:

> redirect_uri URL is not supported

My Facebook app is configured as follows:

> Site URL: http://testlive.net/
>
> App Domains: testlive.net testdev.com

I tried using different settings but it didn't worked for me. What may be reason behind this? Also should the redirect_uri start with http/https ?

Comment: Have you checked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100043/facebook-invalid-redirect-uri-but-the-url-looks-fine-to-me

Comment: Yes, I referred this link but unfortunately it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

I found the answer to my question. For live server the redirect_uri was not configured properly i.e. redirect_uri was **//test.testlive.net** whereas it should have been started with http/https like **http://test.testlive.net**.

> So in future if you face this issue make sure your redirect_uri should start with http or https

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Unfortunately I further run into `Sorry, something went wrong.` error. Any ideas? TIA.